# GUI loading issue on Windows compare to OsX

Tags: c++, windows, macos, user-interface, juce

I use Juce C++ 4.0.2 to build an audio plugin with a relatively heavy GUI. It takes 5s to load the GUI on a DAW like reaper on OsX, but it takes 10 times more on Windows using the same DAW.

I eventually figure out that is it due to the Typeface::createSystemTypefaceFor function that takes 100ms on Windows. It was an issue on my side because I used it many times.

Does anyone face the same issue?

Comment: How many times are you calling it? It should only be called a very small number of times

Comment: Many times in fact, that was the issue :)

Comment: I added it as an answer, please accept (assuming it still answers your question) so this can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Typeface::createSystemTypefaceFor` is not designed to be called frequently; you should call it once for each typeface ideally and cache the results. Calling it frequently will cause a performance hit which varies depending on platform, as you are experiencing.